# STL copy efficency

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, stl

My understanding is that `std::copy` copies the elements one at a time. This seems to be necessary in order to trigger the constructor on each element. But when no such constructor exists (e.g PODs), I would think a `memcpy` would be much more efficient.

So, does the STL require/allow for specializations of, for instance, `vector<int>` copying that would just do a `memcpy`?
The following questions I would appreciate answered for both GCC / MSVC, since those are the compilers I use.

1. If it is allowed but not required, do the above compilers actually do it?
2. If they do, for which containers would this trigger? Obviously it makes no sense for `list`, but what about `string` or `deque`?
3. Again, if they do, which contained types would trigger this? Only built-in types, or also my own POD types (e.g. `struct Point {int x, y;}` )?
4. If they don't, would it be faster to use my own wrapper around `new` / `delete` / pointers that uses `memcpy` for things like integer/char/my own struct arrays?

Comment: `std::copy` arguments may alias, so in general `memcpy` would be unsafe. Usually `memmove` is used instead.

Comment: I think it's an error to assume memcpy is automatically faster. You are ultimately just copying bytes around and the speed primarily depends on how many you copy (plus looping overhead). In some cases memcpy can actually be slower since thanks to padding it might be copying more data than the actual assignment operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, `std::copy` doesn't copy-construct anything. (That would be the job of the algorithm `std::uninitialized_copy`.) Instead, it *assigns* to each element of the old range the corresponding new value.

Secondly, yes indeed, a compiler may optimize the assignment into a memcopy as long as the result is the same "as if" it had performed element-wise assignment. GCC does this for example by having compiler support to recognize such trivially-copyable types, and C++11 actually adds a new type trait called `std::is_trivially_copyable` which is true precisely for types which *can* be memcopied.

Comment: This answer covers underlying type assignment, but the question was about container's type.